# How to get functionality of hidesAccessoryWhenEditing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, deprecated

Since `hidesAccessoryWhenEditing` is deprecated in the iPhone 3.0 SDK, what is the replacement? How do you get the same functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the docs it seems to suggest:

> A Boolean value that determines
>   whether the accessory view is hidden
>   when the cell is being edited.
>   (Deprecated. Use the
>   editingAccessoryType and
>   editingAccessoryView properties
>   instead.)

editingAccessoryType mentions

> The default is
>   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone. If a
>   custom accessory view for editing mode
>   is set through the
>   editingAccessoryView property, the
>   value of this property is ignored.